# **Are there infinite metric spaces which have no infinite compact subsets**

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness

Please if anyone can help me in solving this example:

**Are there infinite metric spaces which have no infinite compact subsets**

If there are, please, that they look like, please help me, thank you, thank you for your answers and your attention, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take the natural numbers with the usual metric.

Take the set $N$ formed by numbers $1,2,3,...$ Put the distance between them to be $dist(a,b):=|a-b|$.

Assume that $A$ is an infinite subset. Notice that any subset of $N$ is open. Cover $A$ by the (open) sets $\{a\}$, for all $a\in A$. There is no way to extract a finite subcover of $A$ from this covering.

Comment: Please if you can explain to me in detail what exactly you need to do

Comment: Done. Check above.

Comment: thanky very much for your solve, its very good answer, I hope this is the final solution